# How to change color scheme of frame extracted via FFMPEG library on C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, video, ffmpeg, color-scheme

I have been able to decode the video file using the FFMPEG as well as to save them in *.ppm files.

I would like to know how can I change the color of each frame soon after decoding and before saving them?

For example: if I have a colored frame which I decoded and extracted from the video file, I would now like to change it to black and white frame and then save it to the file.

I am quite new to FFMPEG library and further more less documentation is available on it for developers. Therefore any help on it would be highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to convert it to gray scale using the sws_getContext method.

My method is here:

```
mpFrameSwsContext = sws_getContext(mpAVCodecContext->width, 
                mpAVCodecContext->height, mpAVCodecContext->pix_fmt, mpAVCodecContext->width, 
                mpAVCodecContext->height, PIX_FMT_GRAY8, PIX_FMT_GRAY8 , NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But in the end the resultant image is as seen as below:

[image]

Can anyone suggest any correction?

Thanks